# Ninja: No work to do when re-building HelenOS

Tags: bash, bsd, ninja

I am trying to make an Operating System using HelenOS and making big changes to it, but I want to re build the OS whenever I make a change to the code, how do I do that? I looked carefully and thought about using the "ninja" command, ninja command is used for building the OS, but whenever I type it in it says ninja: no work to do. How do I fix that?

Here is the link for building the OS: https://github.com/HelenOS/helenos

[Image of ninja command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8Dd0.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.